# When to use Container View Controller ? and does it have any advantages in memory management over normal views in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

When to use `ContainerViewController`? and does it have any advantages in memory management over  normal views in `iOS`? In my application one of the screen is having two separate options which is responsible for different tasks. Should I use two `ContainerView` instead of two separate views. Which option will be more scalable?

Answer (score 4):

Container views and parent/child view controllers don't have a meaningful impact on memory. You would need to have hundreds of view controllers in memory at once before different view structures would have a meaningful impact on your memory use.

Container views and parent/child view controllers are useful as a design pattern. It makes it straightforward to create discrete "tiles" of user interface where the views and the control logic that control them are one drop-in unit. Using parent/child view controllers is also the only way to make `UITableViewControllers` and `UICollectionViewControllers` useful, since those view controllers don't allow any other subviews in their view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

From performance or memory management perspective it will always be equal or better to use `UIView` directly. From scalability it simply depends on what you are building.

A content view from storyboard is just a convenience. In general you can add any view controller as a child to another view controller by calling appropriate methods and adding the view as a subview. What you gain here is that your view controller will receive events that are specific for it while view itself will not.

In general view controller is just a wrapper around `UIView`. Application is designed so you need a root one but after that you might as well do everything with views alone.

Containers are used internally a lot. In reality view controllers may only `present` and `dismiss`. What you see as `push`, `pop`, `set` view controllers are all just using containers. Navigation controller consists of header and container view. Tab bar view controller has tab bar view and container view... Using containers you can easily create your own similar components.

When you use containers you will have a very clean code as you separate logic of each unit to its view controller. But at the same time your code may complicate because you now have trouble communicating between your view controllers. Imagine you have two parts of the screen where each represents a set of objects for a common model. Now it all goes well when there is no correlation between the two; but when first view controller changes an option which now needs to reflect in the second view controller you may need to report to delegate which is a parent view controller which will now report to the other child view controller. And even parent may have ugly code to access it's children. But on the other hand some MVVM procedure may handle this situation very nicely.

Anyway there are no apparent advantages or drawbacks. It depends on what architecture you will use and how you will use it. Both procedures are solvable and both can get ugly.